# Im trying to write a function hide one element, show other

Tags: javascript

Im trying to write a function to be able to reproduce the action of hiding one element and make another appear. I know there is something in JQuery for thor that, but Im not there yet, so wanna solve it just with simple js.

```
const changeDisplay = (elm1, elm2) => {
     let E1 = document.getElementById('elm1').style.display = 'none'
     let E2 = document.getElementById('elm2').style.display = 'block'
     return elm1.addEventListener('click', E1) &&
     elm1.addEventListener('click', E2)
   }

   changeDisplay('not', 'ok')
```

`TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null script.js:6:21`

Comment: What do you expect to return from this assignment: `document.getElementById('elm1').style.display = 'none'` ?

Comment: It is bad practice to use JS to style elements, use JS for functionality and toggle a CSS class to do any design changes.

Comment: `document.getElementById(...) is null` — are you sure you're finding the right elements? Reproduce your approach [in a codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) on a simplest example.

Comment: and what do you expect to be returned from `.addEventListener` && `.addEventListener`?

Comment: Please always show all the relevant code. Include the HTML and CSS here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> let E1 = document.getElementById('elm1').style.display = 'none'
> ```

This is throwing an error because [the element doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), and that's because you haven't used the syntax to create a function.

You are evaluating `document.getElementById('elm1').style.display = 'none'` **imediately** and assigning the evaluated value to `E1`.

A function would be:

```
let E1 = function () { document.getElementById('elm1').style.display = 'none' };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet you try to access `elm1` and `elm2` as strings, so you should remove the `'`. Your last line addEventListener is dubious and I don't understand what you are trying to do.

A best practice when dealing with styling changes in JS is to create CSS classes beforehand and change the class dynamically with JS. Something like that:

```
const changeDisplay = (elm1, elm2) => {
     const E1 = document.getElementById(elm1);
     const E2 = document.getElementById(elm2);
     E1.className = 'display_none';
     E2.className = 'display_block';
     E1.addEventListener('click', /*FUNCTION*/);
     E2.addEventListener('click', /*FUNCTION*/);
   }

   changeDisplay('not', 'ok')
```

Comment: Thank you all. the css and html is not the problem, and I do have the id not in the html. Thats why I didnt post it. I learned a lot from the answers, but I have to keep on studying to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code like the example below to add or remove CSS classes that will hide or show your elements as you want.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
 for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++ ){
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++ ){
      items[i].classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    event.target.classList.add("hidden");
   });
 }
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.item { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item hidden" >Item 2</li>
</ul>
```